# Is there 1-to-many dictionary sql, txt, raw-binary... pictures...?

Tags: language, dictionaries

I'm looking for `sql` or `txt` digitized dictionary `Esperanto`-`English`, 1(word)-to-many(words) or 1(word)-to-1(word).

Is there???

Comment: @das-g,  pleaser review. I've modified question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR:

- ReVo data (XML, GNU GPL v2)

  - <del>http://reta-vortaro.de/tgz/index.html</del> ([archived 2020-03-21](https://web.archive.org/web/20200321203656/https://reta-vortaro.de/tgz/index.html))
  - https://github.com/revuloj/revo-fonto
  - https://github.com/revuloj/revo-fonto/releases
- ESPDIC (structured utf-8 TXT file, CC BY 3.0 unported)

  - see http://www.denisowski.org/Esperanto/ESPDIC/espdic_readme.html
- Tuja Vortaro (distinct formats and licenses for different parts)

  - https://github.com/zoenb/vortaro/tree/master/dictionary-src
- Wiktionary (CC BY-SA 3.0 unported)

  - actually using that as data / dictionary: it's complicated
- Wikidata (CC0)

  - see https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access

---

There are various online (and thus fully digital) Esperanto dictionaries.

Not all of them provide bulk downloads of the underlying dictionary data.

## ReVo

A notable exception is [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/) (Reta Vortaro).

### download

Its content is available in an XML based format at [on GitHub in the repository `revuloj/revo-fonto`, subfolder `revo`](https://github.com/revuloj/revo-fonto/tree/master/revo). To get all of it, either clone [that repository](https://github.com/revuloj/revo-fonto) (if you're familiar with Git) or [download the current content of the `master` branch as a Zip archive](https://github.com/Wilfred/ReVo-utilities/archive/master.zip).

The data also seems to be available in SQLite form at https://github.com/revuloj/revo-fonto/releases.

### license

Although that repository itself doesn't include a license file, I'd assume that its content is licensed under the [GNU GPL v2](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dok/copying.txt), as the links on http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/ seem to indicate.

### format

The XML-based format seems to be defined by DTD files available on [their information-for-(future)-editors page](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dok/redinfo.html) (in Esperanto) and to be explained by their [technical manual](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dok/manlibro.html) (also in Esperanto).

#### alternative downloads & formats

On [the project's mailing list](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dok/revolist.html) [MySQL dumps are published from time to time](https://groups.io/g/revuloj/search?q=%22Aktuala+datumbazo%22) together with recent changes to the dictionary. Whether these dumps contain all the information of the XML files or e.g. only what's necessary to search for articles or to display the indices, I haven't checked.

Even more formats <del>are</del> were available on http://reta-vortaro.de/tgz/index.html ([archived 2020-03-21](https://web.archive.org/web/20200321203656/https://reta-vortaro.de/tgz/index.html))

### ReVo derivatives

#### simpla vortaro

http://www.simplavortaro.org/ is based on ReVo data.

It offers [an HTTP API for querying the dictionary](http://www.simplavortaro.org/informo/api) as well as

- [Python programs](https://github.com/Wilfred/ReVo-utilities) to convert ReVo XML to simpla vortaro's JSON format
- [a Django project](https://github.com/Wilfred/simpla-vortaro) for importing said JSON into a database and for the http://www.simplavortaro.org/ website itself

It doesn't seem to provide the ready-made JSON file for download, nor a database dump, though. Note that the [ReVo XML files in the tools repo](https://github.com/Wilfred/ReVo-utilities/tree/master/xml) are currently very out-of-date. (I don't know whether that's also the case for the online content of simplavortaro.org.)

#### PReVo (Android App)

The Android app [PReVo](http://www.busydoingnothing.co.uk/prevo/) is based on ReVo data.

To convert ReVo XML into its own database, it uses the code from https://github.com/bpeel/prevodb/

#### PReVo (Linux command line program)

https://github.com/bpeel/prevodb/ also has code for a command line program to locally query that database.

The ready-made database doesn't seem to be available for download, though. (Except packaged into the Android app.)

## ESPDIC

http://www.denisowski.org/Esperanto/ESPDIC/espdic_readme.html

## Tuja Vortaro

https://www.tujavortaro.net/ seems to be based on several sources, among them of them ReVo data and ESPDIC. It seems to include all that data in its [source code repository](https://gitlab.com/sstangl/tuja-vortaro). Although the program code for the website is GPL v2 licenced, the dictionary data seems to have various other free licenses.

## Senreta Vortaro (Android app)

Senreta Vortaro is based on Tuja Vortaro data and also includes that in its source code repo https://github.com/zoenb/vortaro, seemingly in the same formats as Tuja Vortaro. (So nothing new here.)

## Wiktionary

Wikipedia's collection of dictionary wikis [Wiktionary](https://www.wiktionary.org/) also has entries on Esperanto words. The content is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0 unported](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and available as database dumps, but actually using that data to build an English-Esperanto lookup list might be challenging or even impossible, due to the following problems:

- Information about English words, Esperanto words and their are-translations-of-each-other relationship may occur on a Wiktionary in any language.
- Although the articles follow certain guidelines, they are essentially semi-structured data in MediaWiki markup language, not structured data, so to process them for any other purpose than simply displaying them or searching through them will require complicated and probably brittle approaches.

## Wikidata

More promising might be the collaboratively edited database [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/), which also contains a fair number of words and translations, because it's used to link corresponding Wikipedia articles in different languages to each other. See https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access for various ways to query [or download](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access#Access_to_dumps) the data. According to that article, the data is CC0-licenced, so you'd be allowed to use it for whatever purpose.

Comment: May, I ask u as option, add Russian-Esperanto variants here, in comments? Do u know? I can see, ReVo - contains Russian, but its spread across many-many files, not too handful... ESPDIC - does contain only en-esp...

Comment: Oh, thanx anyway, will use `ReVo`, and I can see `Tuja Vortaro` - contains many language.. Manythanx.

Comment: A sister application for PReVo is **PoŝReVo** for iOS, same look, same data.

Comment: First link (Reta Vortaro) is broken, but you can access its content [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200321203656/https://reta-vortaro.de/tgz/index.html) on the Wayback machine.

Comment: I finally found the ready-to-use SQL database (SQLite3) at https://github.com/revuloj/revo-fonto/releases

Comment: Thanks @kotchwane. I've edited the answer accordingly. Feel free to [edit] it further if you can improve it.